# NGINX После ввода имени домена в браузерной строке происходит редирект на ip

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, сервер, nginx

Здравствуйте

На сервере использум nginx, ubuntu 14

Указали в конфиге nginx имя сервера: наш домен.

Но почему то при ввоже имени домена в браузере отображается ip адрес.

Хостер сказал что это проблемы при конфигурации сервера на вашей стороне, мол какие то скрипты которые делают редирект на ip. Не понимаю...

Настройки nginx

```
upstream app {
     server unix:/home/deploy/sharetribe/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}



server {
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;



        root /home/deploy/sharetribe/public;

        try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

        location @app {
                proxy_pass http://app;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;

        }

server_name domain.name  www.domain.name;

        location / {
            # root /home/deploy/sharetribe/public;
             try_files $uri @app;
             gzip_static on;
             expires max;
             proxy_read_timeout 150;
             add_header Cache-Control public;
        }
}
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНО:**
Сам запрос через гугл хром инструмент:

```
Request URL:http://mydomain.name/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address:12.123.12.12:80
Response Headers
view source

Response Headers
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 12 Mar 2017 10:37:24 GMT
Location:http://12.123.12.12/
Server:nginx/1.10.2
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:ed2db4bd-784b-4591-8831-b696e3aaff60
X-Runtime:0.011830
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Решил посмотреть через curl:

```
root@a:/# curl -v /home/deploy/sharetribe/tmp/sockets/puma.sock http://mydomain/
* <url> malformed
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) <url> malformed
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   12.123.12.12...
* Connected to mydomain (12.123.12.12) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: mydomain
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
* Server nginx/1.10.2 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.10.2
< Date: Mon, 13 Mar 2017 06:31:26 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Location: http://12.123.12.12/
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Request-Id: 326a22df-4bd5-48d7-b695-bd3654943be0
< X-Runtime: 0.016840
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< 
* Connection #0 to host mydomain left intact
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://12.123.12.12/">redirected</a>.</body></html>root@a:/#
```

Сообщение: **Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache**

Просьба людям разбирающихся, помочь. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Для начала Убрать директиву `proxy_redirect`.

Comment: закомментировал proxy_redirect off;  Перегрузил nginx, аналогично ввожу домен, отображается ip адрес.

Comment: Что говорит инспектор запросов в браузере? Какой редирект отдаёт nginx?

Comment: обновил вопрос.  Я так понимаю это Вы имел ввиду

Comment: Мне кажется надо искать проблему где-то в вашем приложении

Comment: Хм-м... так, из вышеприведённого не очень понятно, запрос вообще до приложения дошёл? Или 301 ответил сам nginx?

Comment: а с помощью какого инструмента можно посмотреть?

Comment: С помощью логов PHP, nginx и вашего приложения

Comment: в консоли вызвал `curl -v /home/deploy/sharetribe/tmp/sockets/puma.sock` выдает ошибку Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache. Обновил тело вопроса.

Comment: Пф-ф, ну, это и не должно было отработать, для обращения в Unix-сокеты у curl отдельный флаг, вы сейчас точно так же пошли через nginx. Попробуйте `curl --unix-socket сокет http://хостнейм/`.

Comment: пробую, ввел со своим доменом ```curl --unix-socket /home/deploy/sharetribe/tmp/sockets/puma.sock http://mydomain/```
: выдает ошибку curl: option --unix-socket: is unknown

Comment: @StefanHansch значит, у вас слишком старый `curl`, этот флаг в 7.40 ввели. И значит, вы через curl не сможете послать запрос в Unix-сокет вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Написать вот так:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain.name www.domain.name "";
}
```

И удалить напрочь

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 12.123.12.12;
   add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
   return 301 $scheme://domain.name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: сделал как у вас: `server_name domain.name www.domain.name "";` Ошибка, к сожалению, осталась.

Comment: какая из ошибок? редирект? "NOT found in DNS cache"? "url: option --unix-socket: is unknown"?

Comment: url: option --unix-socket: is unknown

Comment: но ведь это совсем не относится к теме вопроса... ок, думаю, что при копировании минусы заменились короткими тире. скажи в `curl --help | grep socket` и скопируй этот ключ из вывода.

Comment: ```/# curl --help | grep socket
     --egd-file FILE  EGD socket path for random data (SSL)```

Comment: @StefanHansch обнови curl - пишут, что этот ключ появился в 7.40

Comment: обновил.  ввожу ```curl --unix-socket /home/deploy/sharetribe/tmp/sockets/puma.sock http://mydomain/``` результат: ``` <html><body>You are being <a href="http://12.123.12.12/">redirected</a>.</body></html>```

Comment: https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ruby+on+rails+you+are+being+redirected

Comment: да наверное. буду разбираться. спасибо вам!